# Why does 'new Date() * 1' produce a Javascript timestamp?

Tags: javascript

I have the following methods of obtaining a timestamp:

```
new Date().valueOf()
new Date().getTime()
Date.parse(new Date())
new Date() * 1
```

But I'm confused: why am I able to get a timestamp using the last method?

Comment: Often wondered about this myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `Date()` object can be converted directly to a number (the timestamp), and when applying mathematical operators to it JavaScript converts this for us.

An even quicker way to get the timestamp is to use the Unary Plus:

```
+new Date();
```

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number.
>
> – [MDN's Unary Plus documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()).

The same applies with strings `"1" * 1` equals `1` because JavaScript automatically converts `"1"` to a number because of the presence of the multiplication operator (`*`).

Comment: Reference for Date object on MDN. In case you are interested. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate

Answer (score 1):

One of the weird things about JavaScript is that if you try and perform an operation between two variables, it will try to convert them to a type where it can perform this operation. But this can happen in different ways, so for example `"2" * 2 === 4` is true, but so is `"2" + 2 === "22"` because it goes to the `string` version of the `+` operator first.

When you take a `Date` and try to do multiply or divide it, JavaScript will understand that as converting the Date to it's numerical timestamp value. Consequently the surprising outcome you see above.

However:

```
new Date() + 1
```

Results in `"Tue Jul 07 2015 15:20:17 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)1"` because the date can also be treated as a string.

This is one of the many quirks of JavaScript that will be helpful to understand when you run into that weird bug, but you would be well advised to avoid using in your code if you want to be able to understand it at a glance later ( spoiler warning: You do! )